# ssrs 2008 R2 all parameters are disabled after upgrading a report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, parameters

I have updated an SSRS 2005 report to a different server with SSRS 2008 R2 via Visual Studio 2013. When I preview the new report in Visual Studio, it works. But, after deploying the report, all the parameters are disabled. I cannot input any parameters. Yet, I can access and run reports correctly via Web Service URL (/ReportServer). They are not working if I reach them through Report Manager URL.
Any advise?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you needed to upgrade your report with Visual Studio 2008.   I hope you still have the 2005 code to upgrade with.   Otherwise you may need to completely re-build it in VS 2008.

Comment: .RDLs aren't backwards compatible to my knowledge. Trying to run a report that you opened up in VS 2013 on a 2008 R2 instance will cause schema issues.